# Erro em tempo de execução 13. Tipos incompatíveis

Tags: vba, excel-vba, microsoft-excel

Estava construindo uma listagem simples, e me deparei com o 'Erro em tempo de execução 13. Tipos incompatíveis'. Quando eu depuro ele me diz que o erro está nas duas linhas de código do meu 'If', referentes às datas.

O que acontece é que eu possuo uma listagem, um botão para pesquisar e 4 filtros a serem utilizados - dois deles são ComboBox ('tipos de entradas' e 'status'), e outros dois são TextBox (vencimento: 'data de inicio' e 'data de fim').

A minha intenção é poder usar ou não os filtros. Porém quando clico em 'pesquisar' ele me retorna o erro. Se insiro apenas uma data e pesquiso, erro. Pesquisar com apenas um ComboBox ou ambos, erro. Se não seleciono nada e pesquiso, erro.

Alguém sabe me ajudar? Sou novo com VB, posso estar cometendo um erro básico e não ter percebido. Desde já agradeço.

Obs.: Me deparei com pessoas dizendo que a minha planilha poderia estar protegida mas eu já chequei e não estava.

Edit: No terceiro parágrafo eu cometi um erro mas já corrigi. Na verdade mesmo inserindo data de inicio e fim do vencimento eu tenho encontrado erro. Nenhum dos filtros está funcionando.

```
Private Sub BtnPesquisar_Click()

    LISTAR_ENTRADAS

End Sub



Private Sub TextFim_Change()

    'Formatação para datas

    TextFim.MaxLength = 10

    If Len(TextFim) = 2 Or Len(TextFim) = 5 Then
        
        TextFim.Text = TextFim.Text & "/"
    
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextFim_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    If KeyAscii < Asc(0) Or KeyAscii > Asc(9) Then
    
        KeyAscii = 0
        
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub TextInicio_Change()

    'Formatação para datas
    
    TextInicio.MaxLength = 10

    If Len(TextInicio) = 2 Or Len(TextInicio) = 5 Then
        
        TextInicio.Text = TextInicio.Text & "/"
    
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub TextInicio_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    
    If KeyAscii < Asc(0) Or KeyAscii > Asc(9) Then
    
        KeyAscii = 0
        
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Declaração dos itens no Select
    ComboTipo.AddItem "Pagar"
    ComboTipo.AddItem "Receber"
    
    ComboStatus.AddItem "Realizado"
    ComboStatus.AddItem "Não Realizado"
    

End Sub

Sub LISTAR_ENTRADAS()

    'Declaração das variáveis
    Dim item As ListItem
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Clear
    ListViewEntradas.ListItems.Clear
    
    ListViewEntradas.Gridlines = True
    ListViewEntradas.View = lvwReport
    ListViewEntradas.FullRowSelect = True
    
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Data de Registro", Width:=60, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Tipo", Width:=70, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Valor", Width:=80, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Categoria", Width:=60, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Cliente/ Fornecedor", Width:=120, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CPF/ CNPJ", Width:=100, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Data de Pagamento", Width:=70, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Status", Width:=60, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Observação", Width:=100, Alignment:=0
    
    For i = 2 To Planilha2.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    
        If (ComboTipo.Text = "" Or ComboTipo.Text = Planilha2.Range("b" & i)) And _
            (ComboStatus.Text = "" Or ComboStatus.Text = Planilha2.Range("h" & i)) And _
            TextInicio.Text <= CDate(Planilha2.Range("g" & i)) And _
            TextFim.Text >= CDate(Planilha2.Range("g" & i)) Then
            
            'And _
            'TextInicio.Text <= CDate(Planilha2.Range("g" & i)) And _
            'TextFim.Text >= CDate(Planilha2.Range("g" & i))
            
            Set item = ListViewEntradas.ListItems.Add(Text:=Planilha2.Range("a" & i))
            item.SubItems(1) = Planilha2.Range("b" & i)
            item.SubItems(2) = Planilha2.Range("c" & i)
            item.SubItems(3) = Planilha2.Range("d" & i)
            item.SubItems(4) = Planilha2.Range("e" & i)
            item.SubItems(5) = Planilha2.Range("f" & i)
            item.SubItems(6) = Planilha2.Range("g" & i)
            item.SubItems(7) = Planilha2.Range("h" & i)
            item.SubItems(8) = Planilha2.Range("i" & i)
        
         End If
    
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW: Veja os tipos de dados, você está declarando i como `Integer` que é um tipo de dado antigo e utilizado em muitos tutoriais, mas possui somente 16 bits e após 65 535 ocorre o overflow. Declare como Long de 32 bits com `Dim i As Long`.

Comment: Crie um [mcve] com alguns dados fictícios para reproduzir este erro e veja https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8388/75104

Comment: Tente converter a data para um número Double com `CDbl()`, pois é melhor para realizar operações matemáticas. Por exemplo: `CDbl(TextInicio.Text) <= CDbl(Planilha2.Range("g" & i))`. E é importante verificar se o dado inserido em TextoInicio é uma data, o [IsDate](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) pode ser utilizado.

Comment: Deu certo aqui, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salve, meu caro!

O problema é que você está comparando data com uma string que não é data (e às vezes até mesmo uma string vazia).

Se você deixar uma comparação de cada vez no `If`, verá que o problema não é com as comparações de texto dos `ComboBoxes`, e sim com as comparações de datas. Ao tentar preencher ambas as datas, funcionou.

Portanto, para fazer funcionar mesmo sem uma (ou ambas) as datas preenchidas, basta garantir que a comparação seja válida mesmo que o usuário não preencha uma data.

Existem algumas formas de fazer isso, mas escolhi declarar uma variável do tipo `Boolean` para verificar se é para filtrar por cada uma das datas. Caso o valor da `TextInicio` ou `TextFim` não seja do tipo data, a variável respectiva será `False`; caso seja do tipo data, pode ser usado como parâmetro de busca sem problema.

**O erro que você descreveu só ocorre quando o Excel avalia `CDate(TextInicio.Text)` da caixa de texto vazia, ou quando compara este valor com uma data. Por isso, é preciso colocar a comparação de `TextInicio.Text` dentro de um `If`, para só rodar caso realmente seja uma data.**

Para contornar isso, eu criei uma variável booleana `bolPassouFiltros`. Ela começa verdadeira, e cada filtro pode transformar ela em falsa. Somente se passar em todos ela continua verdadeira e a linha é inserida no `ListView`. A rigor, isso é somente um desmembramento do `If` único, mas é uma das formas de evitar o erro das datas.

No final, o código ficou assim:

```
Sub LISTAR_ENTRADAS()

    'Declaração das variáveis
    Dim item As ListItem
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim bolFiltrarDtInicio As Boolean, bolFiltrarDtFim As Boolean, bolPassouFiltros As Boolean
    
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Clear
    ListViewEntradas.ListItems.Clear
    
    ListViewEntradas.Gridlines = True
    ListViewEntradas.View = lvwReport
    ListViewEntradas.FullRowSelect = True
    
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Data de Registro", Width:=60, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Tipo", Width:=70, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Valor", Width:=80, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Categoria", Width:=60, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Cliente/ Fornecedor", Width:=120, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CPF/ CNPJ", Width:=100, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Data de Pagamento", Width:=70, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Status", Width:=60, Alignment:=0
    ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Observação", Width:=100, Alignment:=0
    
    ' Pega as datas de pesquisa
    If IsDate(TextInicio.Text) Then
        bolFiltrarDtInicio = True
    Else
        bolFiltrarDtInicio = False
    End If
    
    If IsDate(TextFim.Text) Then
        bolFiltrarDtFim = True
    Else
        bolFiltrarDtFim = False
    End If
    
    ' Preenche a ListView
    For i = 2 To Planilha2.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
        bolPassouFiltros = True
        If Not (ComboTipo.Text = "" Or ComboTipo.Text = Planilha2.Range("b" & i)) Then bolPassouFiltros = False
        If Not (ComboStatus.Text = "" Or ComboStatus.Text = Planilha2.Range("h" & i)) Then bolPassouFiltros = False
        If bolFiltrarDtInicio = True Then If Not (TextInicio.Text <= CDate(Planilha2.Range("g" & i))) Then bolPassouFiltros = False
        If bolFiltrarDtFim = True Then If Not (TextFim.Text >= CDate(Planilha2.Range("g" & i))) Then bolPassouFiltros = False
            
        If bolPassouFiltros = True Then
            Set item = ListViewEntradas.ListItems.Add(Text:=Planilha2.Range("a" & i))
            item.SubItems(1) = Planilha2.Range("b" & i)
            item.SubItems(2) = Planilha2.Range("c" & i)
            item.SubItems(3) = Planilha2.Range("d" & i)
            item.SubItems(4) = Planilha2.Range("e" & i)
            item.SubItems(5) = Planilha2.Range("f" & i)
            item.SubItems(6) = Planilha2.Range("g" & i)
            item.SubItems(7) = Planilha2.Range("h" & i)
            item.SubItems(8) = Planilha2.Range("i" & i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

As outras funções não mudaram.

**Outra forma, até mais simples, de resolver**, é criar duas variáveis do tipo `Date` e, antes do seu `If`, rodar um outro `If`: se `IsDate (TextInicio.Text)`, a variável será igual a `TextInicio.Text`; se não, a variável será igual a 0 (no caso da data de início) ou a uma data bem alta (no caso da data de fim). O problema dessa abordagem é que, embora seja mais simples, a data mais alta que você usar pode chegar um dia, aí será tipo um bug do milênio no seu software.

Por fim, uma dica: você pode configurar a propriedade `MaxLength` das caixas de texto uma vez só, em tempo de desenvolvimento (seu código faz isso a cada `KeyPress`, o que implica um processamento desnecessário).

Comment: Nossa cara, ficou muito bom mesmo. Eu testei e cada filtro funciona independentemente, que era o que eu queria. Obrigado pela sua ajuda!

Comment: Feliz por ter ajudado!